# where should c3p0 properties specified?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, c3p0

I am using spring/hibernate integrated application. I have configured c3p0 connection pooling. I am using c3p0 combopooled datasource. Where should I specify combopooled datasource properties?

In this section?

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath:hibernate-mapping.xml" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                **//Here do I need to specify combopooled datasource properties?
        //like acquireIncrement
            acquireRetryAttempts
            acquireRetryDelay
            preferredTestQuery
            maxPoolSize...etc**
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

Or here?

```
<bean id="rootDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
**//Here do i need to specify combopooled datasource properties?
            //like acquireIncrement
            acquireRetryAttempts
            acquireRetryDelay
            preferredTestQuery**
            maxPoolSize...etc

</bean>
```

Please suggest me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify them in a `c3p0.properties` file. Just place it in the root of your classpath

or, in xml file named `c3p0-config.xml` also in the root of your classpath

or, if you want it in you spring xml for Hibernate you can use

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      <!--<property name="lobHandler">
         <ref local="lobHandler" />
      </property>-->
      <property name="hibernateProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${jdbc.drivers}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${jdbc.url}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${jdbc.username}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
```

I believe the Hibernate settings override the use of a c3po.properties file if both exist. however [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081866/is-there-any-reason-to-keep-around-a-c3p0-properties-file-when-you-use-hibernate) suggests some inconsistencies with the c3po docs

Comment: Thanks for your reply. again in which section do i need to access the properties values from properties file?  Thanks!

Comment: If you create the properties file the c3po classes know to look for it in the root of your classpath with that exact filename so you dont have to specifiy this. It should just work.

Answer (score 0):

Those should go on to the data source bean (rootDataSource).  Once you pass a data source to the LocalSessionFactoryBean hibernate will not be creating the connection pool - so the properties specified under hibernateProperties will be ignored.

All the properties you want to set are available as setter methods on [ComboPooledDataSource](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ComboPooledDataSource.html). Add more property tags to your data source bean and specify the value for those there.

```
<bean id="rootDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="..." />
        <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="..." />
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="..." />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="..." />    
    </bean>
```